# Clearing out a char array best scenario - memset or not?

Tags: c++, memset

In my current code I have something like this

```
while(true) //Infinite loop
{
   char buff[60];
   .....
   ....
}
```

I wanted to know what would be better performance wise.

1. Declaring the char buff (that will hold strings that contain linefeeds and new line character) before entering the infinite loop and then using `memset(buff, 0, 60);` or
2. Keeping it the way it is. Does memset affect performance ?

**Note:**

My requirement is that I need to have the `char` array totally clean everytime the loop restarts.

Comment: memset has to do something - but as to which is quicker, try it and see?

Comment: Do you really need to clear it out? It must be populated in the remainder of the loop, so initialization may be unrequired.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those aren't equivalent - after declaring `char buff[60];` the memory isn't guaranteed to be all 0s. If you need the memory to be all 0s, use `memset`, otherwise don't.

Comment: As posted, your array is not initialized, so outside of debug builds it is roughly equivalent to declaring it outside the infinite loop and *not* calling memset.

Comment: and what about `char buff[60] = {0}` ?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/1609356

Comment: @Manu343726 this will not work in my case since buffer will  have multiple line feeds and new lines "\n"

Comment: Is this a buffer for a null-terminated C string? If you want it "empty" for functions like `strlen` and `strcat` you only need to assign '\0' to buff[0].

Comment: If using `memset` to zero out the array works, then `char buff[60] = {0};` works too. And so does `char buff[60] = {};`, as in my answer.

Comment: @Rajeshwar - `char buff[60] = {0}` sets **all** the elements of the array to 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"The way it is" doesn't give you an array full of zeros. But you don't have to call `memset` anyway. If you are only to use `buff` inside of the loop, I think it is better to keep it in the scope of the loop:

```
while(true) //Infinite loop
{
   char buff[60] = {}; // buff is full of zeros
   .....
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`memset` does some work, so it must "affect performance". It's generally heavily optimized though, because it's a common operation.

You're unlikely to find a faster way to clear the array because of this, and for comparison the code you showed does *not* initialize the array at all.

For reference, it should probably look like:

```
char buff[60];
while (true) {
    memset(buff, 0, sizeof(buff));
    ...
```

The only solution likely to be faster is finding a way to stop depending on the buffer being zeroed at the start of each iteration

Answer (score 2):

If you are consistently using it as a C style string:

```
char buff[60];
buff[0] = 0;
```

This will only set the first byte, but if you are using it as a simple C style string, that is all you ever need to set to make it a zero-length string. It is faster than any solution that fills the entire buffer by probably a factor of 7 on a 64-bit machine.

If you actually need the entire buffer filled with 0, then

char buff[60] = {};

will do that.